# Close vote review queue: let me see the answers on a review question

Tags: feature-request, review-queue

I have a minor annoyance/inconsistency with the close vote review queue.

Suppose I’m looking at a question which has been flagged as a duplicate of another question.

- On the flagged question, I can only see the number of answers/whether there’s an accepted answer. I can‘t see the answers themselves.
- On the duplicate question, I can see both the number of answers/whether there’s an accepted answer *and* the answers themselves.

It would be nice if I could see the existing answers on the question I’m about to review, not just related questions.

---

#### Why do I want this?

Particularly when I’m reviewing Story ID questions which have been marked as dupe, I wanted to check the answers on both of them for an OP confirmation that it’s the same story. (Probably unnecessary if it’s already got CVs, but I like to be thorough.)

Right now, I have to click through to the original question, but I can immediately see the answers on the dupe target. That’s mildly annoying. It would be a little easier if the answers on the review question were immediately accessible. *#firstworldproblems*

It would be sufficient if this just occurred on questions with dupe votes, but it’s probably easier and no less arduous to enable it for all close vote questions. But this is a very low priority request – the annoyance is minor at best. But hey, if you don’t ask, etc? :-)

---

#### Screenshots

Original question, with no answers:

[image]

The duplicate, with answers shown below:

[image]

Comment: I'm about 99% sure you'd have to raise this on meta-meta; I also suspect there's some philosophical reason they dont' already do it.

Comment: Personally I want to see all answers on all questions in all review queues (on the site where I have review privileges anyway). But we're apparently supposed to robotically judge everything in a vaccuum so it'll never happen...

Comment: I *think* the idea is that you shouldn't judge if a question is good based on the answers it has; off-topic questions might still get the occasional answer. You can always jump to the question in another tab. (I'm just guessing though)

Comment: And.... you are apparently not alone in wanting this. It seems a popular request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Gah, how was I unable to find that when I was looking just now? My Google fu has failed me… :-(

Comment: @MikeEdenfield From what I've read on MSE that is indeed the case. I happen to strongly disagree with that idea (seeing if a question attracted good answers is the best way to tell if it *should* be closed imo), but that's what I've seen espoused there. Hence I find myself opening a lot of tabs when I do reviews.

Comment: Why would you want this? To look at the flagged question's answers would only allow you to compare its answers to the linked question/answers. When this is not the purpose of the flag. You are reviewing the **question**, not its answers. The only benefit would be to see if answers given to the flagged question *confirm* the suspicion (but that doesn't seem to be a good thing). **IMO**.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently such a popular request, that someone has written a client-side script to implement it.

From an answer to this [existing meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212479/165776):

> Update: [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch v1.10](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) now contains a client-side implementation of this feature. It works by detecting the presence of un-displayed answers (based on the summary table) and loading them via AJAX instead. There's some kluginess involved in reformatting the answer wrapper elements to fit the review page format, but overall it seems to work nice and smoothly.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just click through to the actual Q&A?  And then go back to the review screen.

I do the most close and re-open reviewing here and on Serverfault and on both sites I regularly click on the question link so that I can look at all the comments, any answers, etc.  It's an easy way to get a better picture of what's good or bad about a question.

And although I'm not going to go looking now for the relevant meta.SE posts, it's been clearly stated by SE staff that it's not just *allowed* to do this, it's almost the definition of careful reviewing if you do it.  You don't have to do it, it's not always necessary, but it's totally fine if you do.